# Problem applying css in Django with static-files app

Tags: css, django, static-files

I am using Django and I can't get my style.css to work. Every time I load the page I am working on, no css is applied. Also I get this in the terminal "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2239

My style.css is located in .../Templates/site_media/static/css

I also have djago.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APPS

I have this in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = "/Templates/site_media/",
```

This is what I have in my template to load the css

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: When you view the HTML, what does it show as the `href`? Is the `STATIC_URL` variable passed through to the template?

Comment: What do you mean by is the STATIC_URL variable passed through to the template? I used the <link href={{STATIC_URL}}static/css/style.css ....>

Answer (score 2):

> My style.css is located in
>   .../Templates/site_media/static/css

doesnt match

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

you would need to have your link as:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**Edit** Use absolute paths for STATICFILES_DIRS (thx Yuji):

settings.py:

```
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ((os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'Templates/site-media'),)
```

make sure that your:

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` has `'django.core.context_processors.static',`

Comment: also, the STATICFILES_DIRS needs to be a list or tuple, AND, they need to be absolute paths. I assume `.../Templates` is not `/Templates`.

Comment: good points, although i think the trailing comma will tuplize(?) it.

Comment: I changed my settings.py to the suggestions that kriegar suggested and it still doesn't work. I get this now in the terminal though "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1730

Comment: check to see if your css file is being hosted... type into your browers `http://<site>/static/static/css/style.css` if you don't want the redundant static you should change your STATICFILES_DIR to `((os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'Templates/site-media/static'),)` and your css file should then be hosted at `/static/css/style.css`. However based on the comments above it looks like your `{{ STATIC_URL }}` isn't reaching the template.