# django - not able to load static css file..error

Tags: django

I'm trying to load a CSS file but for some reason it is not able to locate the file. Here is the error that I get while loading the file:

`---[05/May/2013 11:31:58] "GET /static/css.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1625`

```
File structure


Folder structure
      ecomstore
          ecomstore
                 catalog
                 preview
                     Templates
                        Catalog
                        base.html
          static
              css.css
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
import os
admin.autodiscover()

static = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
print 'static=',static

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^catalog/$','ecomstore.preview.views.home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':static}),

    (r'^',include('ecomstore.catalog.urls')),
)
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "XHTML1-s.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head> 
     <title>DJANGO E-Commerce website</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
     <title>{% block title %}{% if page_title %}{{ page_title }} - {% endif %} ?     
          {{ site_name }}{% endblock %}</title> 
     <meta name="keywords" content="{{ meta_keywords }}" /> 
     <meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css.css"
        type="text/css" />

    <script src="/static/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    {% block site_wrapper %}{% endblock %} 
</body>
</html>

settings.py

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `{{STATIC_URL}}` for CSS href in your HTML? Take a look at [Problem applying css in Django with static-files app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5396625/1693859).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from urls.py as its not needed in development:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':static}),
```

And it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

File structure should be like so :

```
.
├── {app_name_1}
│   ├── ...
└── {app_name_2}
    ├── static
    │   └── {app_name_2}  # Put static files in this folder
    │       ├── css
    │       ├── img
    │       └── js
    └── templates
        └── {app_name_2}  # Put templates in this folder
```

Comment: It worked after changing '/static/' to 'static/' ..These small errors sucks...but not sure how to debug these things.